# How to Check the Directory Where WordPress is Installed?

Tags: installation

I have a client who has a live WordPress site.

I logged into their FTP and it's hard to tell what directory it is actually installed.

How can I verify through WordPress interface in what directory it is located in?

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22405/wordpress-upload-file-get-path-to-wordpress-installation

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty: Go to the theme editor and echo `ABSPATH` in a comment of `header.php`.

Comment: Although the OP asks how to do it in WP interface, I haven't included the "interface" part in the Title of the Question because, IMO, this Answer is universal.

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin [Debug Objects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-objects/) and you get all informations about the install.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a lot of wordpress sites or no? If no then just look at the files that have all the wp- prefixes. If yes then ask the client what directory is the domain pointing to. I do not think there is a way to tell this through wordpress itself